# TypeError: db.Game.deleteMany is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, seeding

I'm trying to update an app written in react a few years ago & keep getting an error saying "TypeError: db.Game.deleteMany is not a function"

Seed.js

```
const db = require('./models');
const data = require('./gameData.json');

// Delete
db.Game.deleteMany({}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit();
  }
  
  console.log(result.deletedCount,'games deleted');

  // Create
  db.Game.create(data.games, (err, seededGames) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      process.exit();
    }
    
    console.log(seededGames.length, 'games created successfully');
    console.log('done!');

    process.exit();
  });
});
```

I feel like maybe it needs to be replaced with async/await but can't quite make it work

Comment: The error message is clear. Show the code of the `models`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.